# Creating WP8 in-app video is not generating a .jpg thumbnail

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've been told that when I allow the user to create a video from within my app, a .jpg thumbnail image is supposed to be generated automatically.  However, using windows phone power tools, I can see that only the video is generated, no image.  Here is the code below:

**EDIT: the QUESTION here, is HOW does one GET a thumbnail image from a given video that is saved in isolated storage?**

```
        ' Set recording state: start recording.
Private Async Sub StartVideoRecording()
    Try
        App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded = False

        'isoStore = Await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("IsolatedStore")
        strVideoName = GenerateVideoName()
        isoFile = Await isoVideoFolder.CreateFileAsync(strVideoName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
        thisAccessStream = Await isoFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)
        Await avDevice.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(thisAccessStream)

        'save the name of the video file into the list of video files in isolated storage settings
        Dim videoList As New List(Of InfoViewModel)

        isoSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings
        If isoSettings.Contains("ListOfVideos") Then
            videoList = isoSettings("ListOfVideos")
        Else
            isoSettings.Add("ListOfVideos", videoList)
        End If
        videoList.Add(New InfoViewModel With {.Name = strVideoName, .DateRecorded = Date.Now})
        isoSettings("ListOfVideos") = videoList
        isoSettings.Save()
        isoSettings = Nothing


        ' Set the button states and the message.
        UpdateUI(ButtonState.Recording, "Recording...")
    Catch e As Exception
        ' If recording fails, display an error.
        Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() txtDebug.Text = "ERROR: " & e.Message.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you should stick to the information available in the official documentation, and not rumours from the internet?

Comment: That was super constructive and helpful, thanks.  I was told this by multiple people on this website.  If information on this site is irrelevant and unhelpful - as insinuated by your sardonic tone - then why are you here?

Comment: so, I guess windows phone doesn't have a way to make thumbnails from saved video streams?  So when listing a set of videos, there is no way to visually represent each video...

Comment: What is your question? You've said you've heard one thing but are actually experiencing another. Can you point to the documentation that says an image should be generated?

Comment: Apparently there used to be an image generated in some previous version of windows phone, because I've heard that from multiple developers.  But whatever, what I'm asking is HOW can I get a thumbnail image from a video that I took inside the application.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Phone 7.0 it wasn't possible using the "official" SDK to access the camera other than using [CameraCaptureTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.cameracapturetask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). But using `Microsoft.Phone.InteropServices` library it was possible to create a custom camera view in the application. If you used this `VideoCamera` class, it had an event called `ThumbnailSavedToDisk`, which might be what you have heard about. But apps using `Microsoft.Phone.InteropServices` was never allowed in the Windows Phone Marketplace. You can read more [about it here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/how-videocameracamera-content).

---

To generate a thumbnail from a video file one solution would be to read up on how the MP4 file format works and extract one of the frames and use that as a thumbnail. Unfortunatly I haven't found any libraries that can do this.

Another, but far from optimal solution, would be to play the video in a MediaElement and then render that Control to a bitmap. This can be done with the following code (written in XAML/C#, I don't know VB.net, but should be easy to port):

```xml
<MediaElement 
    x:Name="VideoPlayer" 
    Width="640" 
    Height="480"
    AutoPlay="True" 
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    Stretch="Fill"
    Canvas.Left="80"/>
```

And then to create the thumbnail:

```
// Set an event handler for when video has loaded
VideoPlayer.MediaOpened += VideoPlayer_MediaOpened;
// Read video from storage
IsolatedStorageFileStream videoFile = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MyVideo.mp4", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
VideoPlayer.SetSource(videoFile);
// Start playback
VideoPlayer.Play();
```

And then create the event handler which "captures" the thumbnail:

```
void VideoPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100); // Wait for a short time to avoid black frame
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(VideoPlayer, new TranslateTransform());
    thumbnailImageHolder.Source = wb; // Setting it to a Image in the XAML code to see it
    VideoPlayer.Stop();
}
```

Here is how it looks when using a modified version of the [Video Recorder Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Video-Recorder-Sample-5e800bbf). (The small image with the blue border in the upper right corner is the thumbnail of the recorded video. Behind is the camera Viewer.)

[image]

Comment: `Microsoft.Phone.InteropServices` is available to Microsoft approved partners. But rendering to a surface is the recommended way, as one way or another, it's assumed your application is already rendering the video.